# How efficient would it be to have a plane with the cockpit in the back?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, aircraft-systems, cockpit

Would it be efficient to have a passenger planes cockpit move to the back of the plane, rather than the front? What I have in mind is cameras on the fuselage and nosecone that connects to the cockpit and give the pilot a wider viewpoint

Comment: How would that be better than sitting in the front from the get-go and doing away with, you know, the cameras and screens and such?

Comment: @JohnK I'm asking for a story I'm writing, though I won't go into details.

Comment: Welcome to aviation. SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21861/62) has some related information. It might help if you can tell us why you think it could be more efficient.

Comment: Science fiction?

Comment: @JohnK Based entirely on real-world science, though it is a dystopian future

Comment: @JohnK I wouldn't be asking the question if it were science fiction

Comment: Well you could have the plane as more or less an autonomous drone with a compartment in the back where a human "minder" pilot is there for emergencies to land it of the drone goes haywire, relying on 3D cameras.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: I initially interpreted "efficient" as suggesting that a rear cockpit would be close to the tail control surfaces and no farther away from the wings and engines, so all the control lines etc. would be shorter.  It would be nice to have clarification of what that word actually means in this question.

Comment: He's writing fiction and needs to know if there are any efficiency advantages to such a configuration, that would make a fictional aircraft designed like that technically plausible to the reader, because that configuration is necessary to the plot line.

Comment: Perhaps he was inspired by the Thunderbird's Fireflash, with the cockpit in the vertical stabiliser? https://youtu.be/s1jrIbXTnak

Comment: This adds way too much complication. Just do away with all the complicated stuff

Comment: You mean like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gee_Bee_Model_R  The only real advantage seems to be that you can hang a great big radial engine on the front :-)